# WC Ajax Product Filter - Price Range issue

Tags: wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

I'm using WC [Ajax Product Filter](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wc-ajax-product-filter/) for filtering options .

Unfortunately the price range is showing :

Min Price: ₹NaN

Max Price: ₹NaN

The actual price is not displaying. Please help me out . I'm new to woocommerce .

Answer (score 1):

The issue found out !

The minimum and maximum price range difference for the products was very less. For example - minimum was $65 and maximum was $66, that was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a temporary solution, edit the plugin file: wcapf.php :you can find this in the root of the plugin directory: wc-ajax-product-filter

Now search for the code: getPriceRange
This occurs in 2 spots around line #467 and line #773
On both 2 spots you see an if statement below which uses sizeof() function.
There seems to be some sort of issue with this.

I have fixed the issues of NaN by commenting out the entire if and else statement that uses the sizeof() function, see below code for example.

It's not the best solution, but well it works, untill update.. I will post this to plugin creator as well.

**#469:**

```
//if (sizeof($unfiltered_price_range) === 2) {
```

**#522:**

```
//}
```

**#781:**

```
//if (sizeof($price_range) > 2) {
```

**#840:**

```
//} else {
// empty array
//  return array();
//}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it this way.

Edit **widget-price-filter.php** file.
It's in the folder /ajax-product-filter/widgets/

Replace the following code in **line 125**:

```
<span class="wcapf-slider-value" id="wcapf-noui-slider-value-min"></span> - <span class="wcapf-slider-value" id="wcapf-noui-slider-value-max"></span>
```

By:

```
if ($min_val!=0 &&  $max_val!=0 ) { 
   echo '<span class="wcapf-slider-value" id="wcapf-noui-slider-value-min"></span> - <span class="wcapf-slider-value" id="wcapf-noui-slider-value-max"></span>';
} else{ echo '-';}?>
```

It will replace the NaN values bellow the slider by (-), just change the last line if you want another text there.